# Python - How to make a general batch function for many similarly-structured functions

Tags: python, function

I apologize if this has been asked before but I'm not entirely sure how to articulate this question.

I have created a set of very similarly-structured functions that perform operations on images using PIL.  The inner workings of them are different in some cases, but they all accept the exact same arguments, a path to the image and a path to an output directory.

In some cases I want to be able to call this function on a single image but I also sometimes what to pass it a folder full of images and have it run its magic on all of them.

My question is this: Is it possible to write a general-purpose batch function that will call another function based on its inputs? Essentially I want to be able to input function A, function B, or function C as an argument to function D and have it be called by function D.

Edit: Here are some examples of two functions that I have:

```
def desaturate(in_img, out_dir):
    im = Image.open(in_img)
    converter = PIL.ImageEnhance.Color(im)
    im2 = converter.enhance(0)
    im2.save(out_dir + r"\\" + splitext(basename(in_img))[0] + "_desaturate.tiff")

def save_as_tiff(in_img, out_dir):
    im = Image.open(in_img)
    im.save(out_dir + r"\\" + splitext(basename(in_img))[0] + ".tiff")
```

So then I would like to have a general-purpose function that would accept a folder path as its first argument and then the desired function as the second argument.  Is there a way to accept a string as an argument and then have it somehow convert that to a function call?

Comment: What language/environment? This question is tagged both python and batch...

Comment: Yes, it is. And without more info that's the best answer you'll get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want to process a bunch of files in a directory tree, and you want that directory-processing function to be general purpose, taking a worker-function as an argument to process each image.

If that's correct, here's a simplified example:

```
import os
import sys

def directory_processor(source_dir, out_dir, worker_func, *xs, **kws):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(source_dir):
        for f in files:
            in_img = os.path.join(root, f)
            worker_func(in_img, out_dir, *xs, **kws)


# One of your image-processing functions.
def desaturate(in_img, out_dir, *xs, **kws):
    print 'desaturating', in_img, out_dir, xs, kws

# To experiment with this script, pass the source_dir and
# out_dir as command-line arguments.    
directory_processor(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], desaturate, 'blort', foo = 1)
```

Note that I've included `*xs, **kws` in the function signatures, which would allow you to pass arbitrary positional and keyword arguments down to the image-processing functions, if needed.

Regarding your specific question (*Is there a way to accept a string as an argument and then have it somehow convert that to a function call?*): there is normally no need to do that; you can pass the function itself (rather than a string name) to another function, as illustrated above.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for such a detailed response, and yes, I think this is exactly what I am looking for.  I'm working on something else right now but I'll definitely give this a try later.

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but any reason why you couldn't just do something like this:

```
def doAll(in_img, out_dir, funcs):
    for func in funcs:
        func(in_img, out_dir)

doAll(in_img, out_dir, [desaturate, save_as_tiff])
```